# How to change the data of a sample .pbix?

Tags: powerbi

I want to change the data of a sample .pbix but when I'm updating the data can not find the path of the Excel since I don't have it. Is there a way without having it?

Answer (score 0):

You can check exists source from  Transform data --> data source settings and find the path of exists excel and in case if you did not found you can add other data sources to replace it.
[image]